# Compiling applications using MS Office Interop assemblies

Tags: office-interop

I need to build a C#-application that uses the Excel interop assemblies on a dedicated build-computer. Is there any way to do that without installing MS Office on the build-box?

Comment: Technically, you only need the Office dlls and regsiter them to do so. However, you need to know which dlls from office are the good ones. The best way to get them is by installing Office.
Did you check on the web?

Comment: I tried copying Office.dll, Microsoft.Cbe.Interop.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Execel.dll to the computer and registering them with "regasm", but now I get this error: ´Cannot load type library for reference "Microsoft.Office.Core". Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))´
This seems to confirm that I _must_ install Office: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/02a11067-10dd-4d87-9469-db3be44f5066 :-(

Comment: Aside from the technical implications, it's a license violation to install the DLLs on another computer for which a license does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OpenXMLSDK and use that without having to use the Office binaries on your build box.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en